# View and grouping

Tags: views

I've view with first column as a group (there are screens below where you can see how I do grouping).

I wish to group my list ignoring 'case sensitive'. How would I do it properly?

Thanks!

Here is how my view is built.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [`hook_views_pre_render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) as shown in example below:

```
function MODULE_NAME_views_pre_render(&$view) {
    if ($view->name !== 'view_name') {
        return;
    }

    $view->field['title_1']->field_alias = 'title_uppercase';
    foreach ($view->result as $result) {
        $result->title_uppercase = strtoupper($result->node_title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you do this line
$view->field['title_1']->field_alias = 'title_uppercase'; ?

Comment: It does not work and it can't work. How can it help me?